# Original file name after upload?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

How do you get the original filename uploaded on GAE?

Going based on the following example:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Uploading_a_Blob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blobstore upload handler rewrites the request (removing body, adding blobkey) but leaves all other stuff untouched.

The POST mimetype is `multipart/form-data`, for which GAE/J offers no API to parse. So you need to use 3rd party library to parse parameters - [Apache Commons-FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) (also as [maven artifact](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22commons-fileupload%22)).

Use it in your `post()` handler like this:

```
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();

    FileItemIterator iterator = null;
    try {
        iterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
            String filename = item.getName();
        }

    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        // handle the error here
    }
```

Since it's possible to upload multiple files at once you need to iterate through the set of parameters and get out the one you are interested in.

Comment: Running your solution... the request parameter is null.

Comment: Edited with an example on how to parse `multipart/form-data`